# DMLException error not coming properly

Tags: exception, pagemessages

I am trying to upsert a record and and I am expecting, when I hit the button, then it will check for Invalid Email address, and if there is any then it will show me the error in the pageMessage.

**Class:**

```
try {
  upsert accctObj;
} catch(DMLException ex) {
   ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Random Message')); 
   return

}
```

I checked in the debug log what ex.getMessage() is showing.

```
 INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, User Email: invalid email address: sd: [User_Email__c]
```

But, I am not able to see above message, instead it's coming,

```
User Email:User Email: invalid email address: sd
```

I want it should come

```
User Email: invalid email address: sd
```

Comment: You need to get the error message like you said ex.getMessage() in the catch block and display it.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe : Fun fact, I did and put it in
`ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Random Message'));
return;`

But still Prvious Error message is coming.

Comment: @SFDCGeek: Did you try ex.getDMLMessage[0]?

Comment: @Vignesh : Yeah, tried, same error. Thing is It is doesn't care about what you give in Catch block, It only shows Error message
`User Email:User Email: invalid email address: sd`

Comment: Have you written "return null;" after ApexPages.addMessage() ?

Comment: @snehakem : Yes, I have written.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting error from this line itself or is it some other line ?

Comment: ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage())); return;

Comment: @AmitBangad : If I am using ` 
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage())) `, then I am getting 2 errors:

`User Email: User Email: invalid email address: er
Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, User Email: invalid email address: er: [User_Email__c]`